# class with arrays windows phone 7, is this correct?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

hi im going to create an object called "day" which stores all the users movements for the day(longditude, latitude)..
think of the day as a session, that will be listed in a Listbox, i just want one name but multible longditudes&latitudes.

now is this correct for me to just declare that these are arrays with no popper size??(until an instance is created)

```
    public class day : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    private string[] longitude;
    [DataMember]
    public string[] Longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return longitude;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != longitude)
            {
                longitude = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Longitude");
            }
        }
    }


    private string[] latitude;
    [DataMember]
    public string[] Latitude
    {
        get
        {
            return latitude;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != latitude)
            {
                latitude = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Latitude");
            }
        }
    }


    // Save to isoldated storage (dat file) 
    public void Save()
    {
        ObservableCollection<day> currentDay = IsolatedStorage.Load<ObservableCollection<day>>(App.daysFileName);
        currentDay.Add(this);
        IsolatedStorage.Save<ObservableCollection<day>>(App.daysFileName, currentDay);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any issue with using List<>. are you looking out for better performance? With List<> code is easier to maintain, more readable and of course less bugs.

Comment: @Splendor: +1 I agree that a List<> would probably be a better solution because it sizes itself dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  Arrays in .NET are created and sized at runtime as opposed to compile time.

Comment: @ Zach Johnson, +1 for your answer. Please check my previous comment.

Comment: thanks guys, i've just been saving strings to the isolated storage, but this is a different app and im required to have an unknown amount of longitudes and latitudes saved in one object. i'm just going to add to it in a while loop.

Comment: @Ryan: That sounds like a good usage for a List<T>, since you can just call Add() and it automatically resizes its internal array as necessary.

Comment: i am storing them in isolated storage as a list anyways :P  public static void Save<T>(string name, T objectToSave). been up all night tbh not thinking clearly lol.